SSIS Upgrade from 2016 to 2022 - Script Task Not refreshing Excel File while running the package from SQL Server Agent
We have upgraded our package and integration services from 2016 to 2022.
Package is running fine from local and from cmd using DTEXE, but same package is failed while running from SQL server agent.
After the upgrade we are facing failure in the Script task where we will be opening the excel file and refresh the pivot tables, while executing the job from SQL Server Agent.
**Error Message: **
Source: Refresh Excel and emailing      Description: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'Excel File Path’. There are several possible reasons:    ? The file name or path does not exist.  ? The file is being used by another program.  ? The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.
Logic of the SSIS Package:
•   DFT – Fetched the data from the SQL server and loads into a Excel file. Completed successfully
•   Script Task – Opens the above created Excel file and refresh the pivot table. Getting error in this step.
Trying to understand the issue.
We have tried to check the access issue, where the same proxy account is working with SQL server 2016.
